# Why cant my iframe's src be this page?

Tags: javascript, iframe

The code below creates an iFrame for [this page](http://www.roblox.com/--item?id=19027209). but as soon as it loads, it basically refreshes the page and I lose the iFrame:

```
var ifram = '<iframe id="frame" width="100%" height="1" scrolling="yes"></iframe>';
document.write(ifram);
var iframe = parent.document.getElementById("frame");
iframe.height = 600;
iframe.width = '100%';
iframe.src = "http://www.roblox.com/--item?id=19027209";
```

Comment: Maybe because they do not want you embed their site into yours? Try the same trick with google.com

Comment: It sounds like they have some frame-busting code, specifically because they don't want third parties iframing their site.

Answer (score 2):

The page has a script for [frame busting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller), preventing you from embedding it within your site:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (top.location != self.location) {
        top.location = self.location.href;
    }
</script>
```

Sites can also use an [`X-Frame-Options` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) to prevent embedding, such as [google.com](http://google.com).